# Cant obtain payKey ios PayPalMPL SDK 1.6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I cant seem to retrieve the payKey string from the delegate method:

```
 - (void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus
```

When setting break points at the delegate methods, non of the delegate methods are being called from the delegate view controller.

I have checked this on the DemoApp supplied by PayPal using the SimplePayment method and setting the break points in the FourButtonVIewController as well as my own application with PayPal integrated.

This has been checked on both a device running iOS6 and iOS5 and the simulator running iOS6.

Can anyone shed any light on this as I cant seem to nail it down ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you setting the delegates?

Comment: @vishy yes. This is happening also on PayPal's own demo application. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

I was incorrectly initializing the PayPal session so the call backs were not getting triggered.

The problem with PayPals own app was me putting breakpoints for the correct delegate on the wrong view controller - PayPal include 2 demo apps, SimpleDemo and InteractiveDemo. I was running Interactive demo but breakpoints were on SimpleDemo. Silly me ;)

Thank you to all who looked!!

Comment: hi i want to ask someting about preapproval key of paypal you know about that?? i just want to know how to get that??